# How would I get it to repeat?

Tags: java

So my assignment says to Write a method called repl that accepts a String and a number of repetitions as parameters and returns the String concatenated that many times. For example, the call repl("hello", 3) should return 
"hellohellohello". If the number of repetitions is zero or less, the method should return an empty string.

So this is one of the codes I have written.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the word");
        String word = console.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int y = console.nextInt();

            repl(word, y);

   }

  public static String repl(String word, int y) {
        if (y <= 0) {
            return null;
        }else {
            System.out.print(repl(word, y)); //line 21, error is here
        }
    return word;
    }

}
```

Currently this code is compiling but when I run it, it prints out

```
at Hello.repl(Hello.java:21)
```

over and over again.

I have also written a for code that will only print out the word once. I have been working on this for about an hour now and I am still very confused as to how I can make the word repeat y times.

Can someone please help me understand this code?

Comment: You need to decrement `y` on recursive calls to `repl`. Wouldn't it be easier to use a `for` loop?

Comment: For future reference, the repeated `at Hello.repl(Hello.java:21)` isn't output from your program.  It's the stactrace on the Stack Overflow error your program had.  And there's more to it than what you just copied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the *decremented* value of `y`:

```
public static String repl(String word, int y) {
    if (y <= 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        System.out.print(repl(word, y - 1));
    }

    return word;
}
```

This way, each iteration of the recursive call will lower the count by 1, ending when it reaches 0.

Note, you'll probably want to return `word` when `y` reaches `0`, as it needs to be printed one last time:

```
public static String repl(String word, int y) {
    if (y <= 0) {
        return word;
    } else {
        System.out.print(repl(word, y - 1));
    }

    return word;
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/PeLMqc)

At this point, notice we return `word` no matter what, which makes the first `if` condition unnecessary.  Your entire function could be reduced to:

```
public static String repl(String word, int y) {
    if (y > 0) System.out.print(repl(word, y - 1));

    return word;
}
```

Of course, this is probably much easier to do with a `for` loop, but I'm assuming recursion is part of your assignment.

Comment: I have made the change you told me to, but if I put the y value equal to 3 it prints it out 2 times, and i put the value as 6 it prints it out 5 times. How can I fix this?

Comment: @user2963042 - I've added some more examples.  Hopefully everything makes sense, but if not, step through each line with a debugger to tell exactly what's going on.  Recursion is a bit tricky to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`y` is not being decremented anywhere inside `repl(String word, int y)`

Comment: what do you mean it is not being decremented? I do not know what that means.

Comment: you aren't subtracting 1 from it.  Therefore your function runs forever and never gets to the end case, where the string is actually printed.  y--;

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is what you have to do:

```
    string toPrint = "";
    for (int i=0; i<y; i++)
    {
        toPrint += word;
    }
    System.out.println(toPrint)
```

This for loop adds the "word" variable to an empty string the required amount of times, and then you just print that variable.

Unless of course you need to use recursion...

Answer (score 0):

1. Decrement y
2. null is not an empty string. Try replacing it with ''.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code

System.out.print(repl(word, y));

to

System.out.print(repl(word, --y));

In your code, the value y is not changed. so the method repl will be in infinite recursive.

Comment: I have made the change you told me to, but if I put the y value equal to 3 it prints it out 2 times, and i put the value as 6 it prints it out 5 times. How can I fix this?

Comment: In your code in repl method, when y<=0 you need to check when word is null or not. Using the following code you can see the expected result. if (y <= 0) { return word==null? null: word; }

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?